# C#: Socket: Cuts my message on the same position always

Tags: c#, sockets

From y Corona App I send a message, using LUA Socket, and it reports that everything looks good (Message shortened down):

```
{,"Seats":{"SeatPosition":1,"Player":"FirstName":"J","LastName":"C","PlayerID":"123"}},"SeatPosition":2,"Player":"FirstName":"T","LastName":"W","PlayerID":123}},"SeatPosition":3,"Player":{"FirstName":"T","LastName":"W","PlayerID":123}}]}} - 1508 <-- Bytes sent
```

Then on the C# server I starts to receive the message and if it's a shorter message it works fine (like a login message which only contains an ID and such).

This is the error message that the server throws:

```
PlayerClient.OnData: Exception: Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException: Unterminated string. Expected delimiter: ". Path 'Table.Seats[2].Player.FirstName', line 1, position 4096.
```

This is the OnData method:

```
 public void OnData(byte[] data)
    {
        string json = "";
        try
        {
            var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings()
            {
                TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.All
            };
            json = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(data);
            Console.WriteLine(json);
            Command c = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Command>(json, settings);

            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("PlayerClient.OnData: Exception: " + ex.ToString());
            Console.WriteLine(json);
        }

    }
```

This is where it cut offs the message (earlier part removed):

```
 Name":"Tomas","LastName":"Westerlund","PlayerID":123}},{"SeatPosition":3,"Player":{"FirstName":"T
```

And the other part seems to be received later:

```
 ","LastName":"W","PlayerID":123}}]}}
```

I can see in the message that there is a lot of space left in the array but I still tried to change the size of the byte array to make it bigger but with no difference. The message is cut off at the same place.

This is how the actual message is received:

```
 currentSocket = s;
 //TODO: Get the actual length of the message.
 byte[] data = new byte[4096];
 int res = s.Receive(data);


 if (res == 0)
     RemoveSocket(s);
 else
     sockets[s].OnData(data);
```

Any idea why the server is not reading the whole message?

Comment: The result from calling `Receive` returns the number of bytes returned. You can't guarantee everything will be received in one go. You need to keep calling `Receive` until the return value is 0. It's not clear that you are doing this.

Comment: Equally, a single `Receive` may actually contain (parts of) multiple messages. Basically, if you want to deal in "messages", it's up to you to implement messages on top of the TCP "stream of bytes" metaphor.

Comment: Thanks, after your help I noticed that the whole "stream of bytes" was not received. Understanding that concept helped me figure out how to solve it. http://www.stratus.com/blog/openvos/?p=369